# Не выходит запушить проект на github.com через IDEA

Tags: github, intellij-idea

К сожалению ответов на свой вопрос в похожих топиках не нашёл, поэтому прошу простить, если вдруг повторяюсь
В общем суть в том, что IDEA без труда подключается к гитхабу, то бишь операция подключения и создания репозитория проходит успешно, но вот файлы не пушатся и вылезают такие вот ошибки:

> Push failed
>            Failed with error: Error: Could not find or load main class org.jetbrains.git4idea.http.GitAskPassApp
>            error: unable to read askpass response from 'C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Temp\git-askpass-0.bat'
>            error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
>            fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No error

При этом я не совсем могу понять, в папке проекта есть созданная папка .git, т.е. попытка подгрузки всё же идёт, но зачем он всё равно лезет к какому-то батнику в AppData я понять не могу - через идею просто первый раз пробую добавить проект, до этого пробовал через стандартное приложение GitHub и GitHubSSH - успешно, но приходилось папку проекта закидывать в стандартный репозиторий .git в документах.

В SettingsRepository пробовал прописывать и URL и просто путь к проекту -D:\IDEA projects\2 project, но я так полагаю, что эти настройки для импорта проектов, а не для экспорта

Comment: вероятно, стоит сообщить разработчикам об ошибке.

Comment: не думал, что такой совет будет) хорошо, поищу контакты, попробую)

Comment: проблема решилась, скорее всего папка проекта просто должна быть вынесена в место, где в каталогах нет символов, кроме английских(т.е. папки названые по русски не канают).

Comment: @go2bed оформите, пожалуйста, Ваше решение в виде ответа, либо исправьте текст вопроса, указав в нём вариант решения, и закройте вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема решилась, скорее всего папка проекта просто должна быть вынесена в место, где в каталогах нет символов, кроме английских(т.е. папки названые по русски не нужно использовать).

Comment: Столкнулся с этой проблемой в 2020 после обновления Android Studio. Кириллицы в пути к проекту нет, так что, проблема была точно не в этом.