# git push выдает ошибку "fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Invalid argument"

Tags: git, github, git-push

по порядку.

1. дома создал репозиторий на github, склонировал его в локальный, добавил файлы отправил командой Push - все ОК.
2. на работе же не проходит команда Push - выдает такие ошибки:
   error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
   fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Invalid argument

настройки (в локальной папке .git) синхронизировал, все равно не помогает.
может это с правами на рабочей машине связано? windows 7, домен

Comment: Проверьте что у вас покажет команда `get remote -v`

Comment: origin  https://github.com/1823244/FortsPosition.git (push)

Comment: Попробуйте такую команду: `git remote set-url origin https://1823244:{password}@github.com/1823244/FortsPosition.git` указав свой пароль вместо `{password}`

Comment: Проверьте путь к проекту, возможно это из-за русских символов, как в данной ситуации http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464448/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-github-com-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-idea

Comment: @ЮрийСПб хранить логин и пароль в открытом виде в файле небезопасно.

Comment: @edem, ну, работать-то будет... Можно и, вроде, чрез ssh подобным же образом настроить что, пожалуй, будет лучше)

Comment: попробуйте поставить gui клиент гит, на работа и проверьте работу с репозиторием по https://

Comment: в пути нет кириллицы

Comment: через "git GUI" уходит нормально